# Best Maple locations after a dungeon in Oracle of Seasons?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

## Background

Maple appears after defeating a certain amount of enemies ([30 or more](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Maple#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Oracle_of_Ages_and_Oracle_of_Seasons) without [Maple's Ring](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Maple%27s_Ring)), and dungeons contain a lot of enemies.

As soon as you leave a dungeon, you're bound to encounter maple.

## Problem

Some areas are filled with water or have holes, causing many items to fall in, becoming unobtainable.

Some areas large amounts of clipped areas, not allowing you to pick up most items, due to them being out of reach.

## Question

With gale seeds unlocked, which areas should a player teleport to (or walk to) after a dungeon, with intentions to encounter Maple, ensuring the lowest change of items dropped by Maple into an out-of-reach area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Best Location

Somewhat in the middle of the map, in north Horon, there is a scent seed tree that you can warp to by using gale seeds. Walk one spot south from there and you should be at a location where Maple can spawn. It is a very open place with no water, or holes.

## Other Suggestions

East, South, and South East of the lost woods are locations where Maple can spawn, they are not optimal, with a lot of holes. Like Likes keep spawning infinitely (I'm not sure about the east screen, but they spawn infinitely on the south and south east screen). It is very easy to trigger multiple Maple encounters there.

In the Tarm ruins in the north west corner of the map there are 4 screens where maple can spawn, the three that are the most north appear to be good places to encounter her. There is a tree nearby that you can warp to with gale seeds.

These next two screens appear to be difficult to reach without triggering an encounter with Maple on your way to those locations:
Impas home (I don't know the correct english name) is reasonably open.
If you go 2 screens south from the Maku Tree, then that area is also fairly open.

## Maple Map

I used this map to know where to go. Note that the map can vary based on your animal companion, in my case I have Dimitri and the map in-game looked a bit different. I did not change the season, some places may be better if you have a different season than the default season for that location.

[image: Map of the world in oracle of seasons with Maple locations, I found the map here (https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gbc/198972-the-legend-of-zelda-oracle-of-seasons/faqs/12198)]

Comment: Very nice find! I'm going to create a formula that weighs each location to determine the best one. I'd rather not risk encountering Maple in a bad area, so I'll most likely exclude those areas. Other factors would include pathing (obstacles may reduce chance of reaching item) and cuttables (grass, signs, etc..). Thanks for this! +1, however, it doesn't give a concrete answer - I'm still required to dig further to determine the best location. Extremely helpful, but I'm going to hold off on accepting for now, as I'm still unsure of the best spot. You gave good suggestions, but it's not concrete.

Comment: The one in north horon is the easiest to reach and very open, you should be able to get there fairly early, too. There are basically no obstacles at all and there are some patches of grass, but you can simply walk over them (short grass). I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: There are some screens before the lost woods, those have a few holes and are not optimal, but they are somewhat decent and they have an infinite supply of like-likes nearby.

Comment: That North Horon one took the cake. I haven't confirmed this is the best yet, and I still plan on debunking this fully. However, out of the 80 tiles on screen, only 21 tiles are inaccessible, all inaccessible tiles are on the edge of the screen, there are no obstacles on the map (excluding edges), and there are only 2 spaces where an item may be unobtainable if landed there (top corners of screen). Excellent location, definitely deserving of accepted answer.